# Lazy selecting rows in polars?

Tags: python-polars

I've written a lazy data-processing function with polars to process a large parquet dataset. Is there a way I can select N rows from the parquet file and return a lazy dataset? I notice that both `.fetch(N)` and `.head(N)` return DataFrames, not LazyFrames. Do I have to do e.g. `pl.scan_parquet(filename).fetch(100_000).lazy()`?

My dataset does not have a monotonically increasing `id` column.

The intention is to see if my function finishes in reasonable time on a large slice of the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I had simply overlooked `.limit()`. Usage is then:

```py
pl.scan_parquet(filename).limit(n=N)
```

It looks to me like the `.fetch()` operation will recursively perform a `.limit` throughout the lazy query, which will allow fast debugging.